# How can I make my SQL inner join bypass a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, inner-join

I've got these four database tables:

```
civilizations(
    civilization_id    PRIMARY KEY
    civilization_name
    civilization_leader
)

cities(
    city_id            PRIMARY KEY
    civilization_id    REFERENCES civilizations.civilization_id
    city_name
    city_population
)

city_buildings(
    city_building_id    PRIMARY KEY
    city_building_name  
    city_id             REFERENCES cities.city_id
    building_id         REFERENCES buildings.building_id
)

buildings(
    building_id         PRIMARY KEY
    building_name
)
```

I want to write a SELECT statement that displays the name of each individual building (stored in city_building_name), the type of building (stored in building_name), the name of the city it's located in (stored in city_name), and the name of the civilization which controls that city (stored in civilization_name).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT city_buildings.city_building_name, buildings.building_name, cities.city_name
FROM city_buildings
INNER JOIN buildings ON city_buildings.building_id = buildings.building_id
INNER JOIN cities ON city_buildings.city_id = cities.city_id
```

That query works and gets me the first three of my required fields, but I don't know how to also get the names of the civilizations which control each city, because the city_buildings table that I've specified after FROM doesn't directly reference the civilizations table with the civilization_name field in it, and I don't know how to write an INNER JOIN that will bypass the cities table and get the value I need from the civilizations table.

The relational database management system I'm running is MySQL. Please could any full answers be posted as proper replies, not just as comments under my question post (but any questions are fine in comments). Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to bypass the cities table?

Comment: Because to get the value stored in the civilization_name field, I need to go through the cities table into the civilizations table.  Sorry "bypass" might be an inaccurate word to describe what SQL does in these situations. I just mean go through the reference into cities, then go through the next reference into civilizations to find the corresponding civilization_name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `civilization_id` from the `cities` table to join with the `civilizations` table and get the name of the civilization from there.

```
SELECT
   cb.city_building_name,
   b.building_name,
   ct.city_name,
   civ.civilization_name
FROM city_buildings cb
INNER JOIN buildings b 
    ON cb.building_id = b.building_id
INNER JOIN cities ct
    ON cb.city_id = ct.city_id
INNER JOIN civ
    ON civ.civilization_id = ct.civilization_id
```

In long joins sometimes is useful to use aliases to make the query more readable.

> A table reference can be aliased using tbl_name AS alias_name or tbl_name alias_name:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: To add a bit of extra information to this. There are three reasons to add a join. To get data for a columns you want to see, to connect to another table even though you don't need anything from that table, to filter records (either through the need to be in that table or through a where clause using a field from that table). This join is needed for the second reason.

Comment: Thanks, but could you tell me what the reason for the lone 'b' character at the end of the 7th line was?  The query wouldn't work until after I deleted that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was gonna use aliases on the table names to shorten the query.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit knew to SQL, but wouldn't those aliases have to be declared somewhere/somehow before running this query, so that the system knows what we're referring to?

Comment: Not really, it's just a shorthand notation to refer to a table or a column name.  I just added more info in the answer.